# Laravel: how to disable cache/storage

Tags: laravel, caching

If, in my someview.blade.php i put the following:

```
<?php die(__FILE__); ?>
```

I get "yada/yada/storage\framework\views\93cc41a18187e11e64fa92c9a2137d20.php

Ive tried:
in .env

```
CACHE_EXPIRE=-1
CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

In config/view.php:

```
return [
    'paths' => [resource_path('views'),],
    'compiled' => env('VIEW_COMPILED_PATH', realpath(storage_path('framework/views'))),
    'cache' => false
];
```

And, I tried removing the `'compiled'` line, but that gives me an error:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Please provide a valid cache path.
```

I just want to go uncompliled or uncached or whatever, so I can see the actual files being used.  I guess as a last ditch workaraound, if there was a global that held the actual file and line number, where I could do like:

```
<?php die($theactualfile.$theactuallinenumber); ?>
```

Comment: If you want uncompiled php files don't use the .blade.php extension. Just use .php